# Solve ODE using undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Use the method of undetermined coefficients to find a general solution
>   $$y'' - 6y' + 9y = 3e^{3x}$$

And the first thing I did, is that I found two linearly independent solutions of the associated homogenous ODE which can be solved,

$$ r^2-6r+9 = 0 --> (r-3)^2 -- > r=3,3$$

$$y_c(x)=c_1e^{3x}+c_2xe^{3x}$$

and from here I know I have to find $y_p = $ particular solution but I have no clue how to find that.

my professor told me that it is

$$y_p = e^{3x}xe^{3x}Ax^2e^{3x}$$

which I have no clue how he came up with that kind of equation.. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant $y_p=Ax^2e^{3x}$. This is because in general, for the right hand side $3e^{3x}$, we use the trial solution $y_p=Ae^{3x}$. But in this case $e^{3x}$ is already a solution for the homogeneous solution. By the multiplication principle, we can use $Axe^{3x}$. However it is again a solution of the homogeneous equation. So we try $Ax^2e^{3x}$.

Comment: yes! thank you very much